# Copy image and text to clipboard together

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to copy an image from a picture box and text from a textbox to the Windows clipboard together, so that they can be pasted into Word.

I'm using the following code:

```
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(pb1.Width, pb1.Height)
    pb1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, pb1.Width, pb1.Height))

    Dim dataobj As DataObject = New DataObject
    dataobj.SetText("This image is a graph")
    dataobj.SetImage(bmp)
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataobj, True)

    bmp.Dispose()
```

Only the text is copied, but commenting out the `SetText` line causes the image to be copied.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried using two data objects or a list of dataobjects?

Comment: Multiple objects didn't work. How do you do a list?

Comment: It works fine for me... I can paste the text into Notepad, and the image into Paint. How did you check that the image wasn't copied?

Comment: They won't paste together into word, wordpad etc.

Comment: @dave88, what do you mean by "together" exactly? When you paste into an app, it only takes one format, not all of them...

Comment: If you want the text to be part of the image, you need to draw it on the image.

Comment: For instance - you have an image and some text in a word document, you do select all, copy and paste into another word document or another application like wordpad. The image is preserved and the text is editable.

Comment: @dave88, that's because the content is copied as rich text (RTF) and/or as HTML. Have a look at the content of the clipboard after you copy some image+text from word.

Comment: Should I copy paste the image and text into a richtextbox then copy from there then?

Comment: @dave88, well, some way or another, you'll have to put some RTF or HTML in the clipboard. You don't have to use a RichTextBox, though, you can generate the RTF or HTML yourself.

Comment: How do I generate RTF without using a control?

Answer (score 1):

The data formats are for retrieval depending on the context i.e. the bitmap will paste into Paint, and the text will paste into Notepad.

This code demonstrates that you can retrieve them both in .NET. when you specify each format

```
Dim data As New DataObject()
data.SetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, True, Me.pb1.Image)
data.SetData(DataFormats.Text, True, "This image is a graph")
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, True)
Dim bResult As Bitmap = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap)
Dim tResult As String = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text)
```

As another test, put both the image and the text into Word, and copy them both. Then inspect what ends up in `tResult` and `bResult` (commenting out the `SetDataObject` line of course). You will notice that `tResult` has your string, but `bResult` is null. You might be able to solve it if you can figure out what format the bitmap is in when it's copied from Word, and use that format when setting it in .NET.

**EDIT**

Copying only the image from Word does put a bitmap into `bResult`, but when it is copied along with anything else, `Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap)` is null.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for pasting into an Outlook email:

```
        ' Put the image on the Clipboard
        Clipboard.Clear()
        Clipboard.SetImage(image)

        Dim rtb As New RichTextBox
        With rtb
            ' Paste the image into a RichTextBox and add the text
            .Paste()
            .AppendText("Your Text")
            .SelectAll()

            ' Create a DataObject with the RTF and put it on the Clipboard
            Dim dataObj As New DataObject
            dataObj.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, .SelectedRtf)

            Clipboard.Clear()
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj)
        End With
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting bitmap directly to the Clipboard like:

```
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(pb1.Width, pb1.Height)
pb1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, pb1.Width, pb1.Height))

Dim dataobj As DataObject = New DataObject
dataobj.SetText("This image is a graph")

Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataobj, True)
Clipboard.SetDataObject(bmp, True)

bmp.Dispose()
```

Comment: This only copies the image and not the text.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque My bad. `Clipboard.SetDataObject` clears the clipboard before adding the data object.